# Incrementar número conforme se dé scroll con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

quiero hacer lo siguiente:

Calcular el tamaño del scrollbar al 100% y lanzarlo al final, para que conforme el usuario vaya moviendo el scroll hacia arriba, el número de metros vaya incrementando pero en decimales:

ej:

Metros: 0, 0.01, 0.02, hasta llegar a 13

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#scroll").scroll(function() {

        var scrollTop = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
        var bottom = $("#scroll").height();

    metros = bottom/13;
    metros=Number.parseFloat(metros).toFixed(2);

        jQuery('.metros p').each(function() {

            var porcentajeScroll = (13 * 100) / bottom;
            var porcentajeTotalScroll = Math.round(porcentajeScroll);

            for (int i = 1; i <= porcentajeTotalScroll; i++) {
                var porcentajeMetros = (13 / 13) * 100;
                var porcentajeTotalMetros = Math.round(porcentajeMetros);
                metros = porcentajeTotalMetros;
            }
            var text = jQuery(this).text();
            var texto = jQuery('.metros p').text();
            jQuery(this).text(text.replace(texto, .metros));

        });
    });
});
```

```css
#scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 0;background-color: #e3e3e3;border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;}
  #scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 10px;}
  #scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {border-radius: 10px;box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);background-color:#587e42;border: 1px solid #587e42;}   
  #scroll{position:relative;width:10px;height:100vh !important;z-index: 2;overflow:auto;position: absolute;top: 0;right: 3em;}
  .mmetros p{font-size: 5em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <div id="scroll">
          <div style="height:1190px;"></div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="metros">
          <p>2</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compañero, creo que logro entender lo que deseas, puedes probarlo de esta manera.

```js
$(function() {
        $.fn.calc_height();
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            $.fn.calc_height();
        });
    });

    $.fn.calc_height = function() {
        var window_scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        var window_scroll_top_cm = window_scroll_top * 0.026458333;
        $('.currentheight').html( window_scroll_top_cm.toFixed(2) + ' cm' );
    };
```

```css
.currentheight {
    position: fixed;
    min-height: 120px;
    width: 252px;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="scroll">
  <div style="height:1190px;">
    <div class="currentheight">Datos</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo, y ¿Cómo sería que el scroll comienze desde abajo y no por arriba?. Saludos...

Comment: **Lo tengo,** solo  invertí el div: `#scroll{transform:rotate(180deg);}`